# Can a class inherit the properies of a namedtuple?

Tags: python, namedtuple

I have a named tuple.

```
import collections

MyNamedTuple = collections.namedtuple('MyNamedTuple', 'prop1 prop2 foo bar')
```

I would like to define a class that can be initialized by these named tuples.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.prop1 = t.prop1
        self.prop2 = t.prop2
        self.foo = t.foo
        self.bar = t.bar
```

The larger `MyNamedTuple` is the more typing I have to do to define `MyClass` so I'm curious if there is a more efficient way to define `MyClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple options... `namedtuple` returns a class -- You can subclass it directly:

```
class MyClass(MyNamedTuple):
    ...
```

Of course, this means that `MyClass` *is* a `tuple` which might not be desirable...

You can also use the [`_fields`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._fields) attribute of the namedtuple (It's documented -- the leading underscore is to prevent property name collisions rather than to indicate that it is a "private" member)...

```
def __init__(self, t):
    for field in t._fields:
        setattr(self, field, getattr(t, field))
```

Of course, this kind of setting via introspection isn't always the most clear thing to read either (and might cause spurious linter warnings) ...

Otherwise, there isn't a really good way to make the linters happy *and* have really short code and writing them all out may be your best option.  If the number of fields in the namedtuple is expected to change at all in the future, I'd advise that you have a unit-test that checks a freshly created `MyClass` against the `MyNamedTuple` that was used to create it to make sure that all of the properties of `MyNamedTuple` are being set.  You *could* (and probably *should*) use the introspection from `_fields` to do this check.